is this Undefined Behavior? (casting away const from a temporary binding to const reference)
is the following code undefined
auto main() -> int {
    const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(42)) = 21; return 0;
}

I am assigning a value to a temporary that was bound to an lvalue that is const then assigned the meaning of life to it.
Do I need this at all? Nope just curiosity kills me. Is this UB?

int const& is the lvalue there is 2

It's a type that can be used for an lvalue, but in your case there is no real lvalue (it doesn't have a name). Or do I miss something ?

@wohlstad Not all lvalues are named.

Rule of thumb: If you can't do it without const_cast (possibly by rearranging code), then you can't do it with const_cast. The only applicable use of const_cast is when you have a non-const object, pass it to a function that accepts const reference and cast away constness inside.

@HolyBlackCat is static_cast<int const&>(42) considred an lvalue ?

@wohlstad Yes? You can confirm by applying decltype to it an observing that it results in an lvalue reference. decltype encodes the value category of the expression into the reference-ness of the resulting type.

@wohlstad Yes it is an lvalue. And the program has UB.

@user12002570 To prove this is UB we need to check if 42 materializes into const int rather than int, and this is far from obvious.

@HolyBlackCat, user12002570 I admit it goes against my intuition about lvalues, but certainly good to know.

@HolyBlackCat The materialization happens and it(the temporary) is bounded to const int&. And casting away const and then assigning to is UB.

@user12002570 not all casting const is UB, you can cast away const if the original object was not const but in this case is the '42' materilized into a const int or a normal int?

@user12002570 the following is well formed and not UB int a;const int& cref = a;const_cast<int&>(cref) = 69;

@user24551355 That doesn't mean that those aren't real issues with your code.

@user12002570 the real issue with the code is why I am doing this code in the first place.

@wohlstad shouldn't nitpick about my way of declaring return values

@sweenish Writing "auto main() -> int  is fancy way of writing int main()" is not being hard-nosed. It is a fact that the former is fancy way of writing the latter. And there's nothing wrong in pointing out a fact.

@sweenish you might be right. But seeing the words "don't complain" against a contributor I felt the urge to respond ... I just think we should keep a civil tone here.

@wohlstad I agree with maintaining civility. But only going after the person reacting (after being prodded multiple times over the smallest of nits) and not the person inciting the reaction is wrong. It wasn't an isolated outburst, and at the end of the day, wasn't even all that rude. If we're going to dole out chastisements and advice for better behavior, it should be going to everyone involved.

@sweenish fair enough.

@Alex If we're going to be hyper-literal and not use surrounding context, sure. Pointing out facts is usually a good thing. But taking in the context of this discussion, pointing out that fact at that time was unnecessary and antagonistic. Especially when stated bluntly like it was.

@Alex I am sorry but if someone knows the trailing return syntax then he for sure knows the normal syntax no need to point out a fact we already know and the comment wss unnecessary focus on the question

@Alex what else is he going to say returning zero from main is is more complex than leaving it out?? focus on the question that is all I am asking.

And just to go full circle, the [mre] page starts with this: "When asking a debugging question [...]". This is not a debugging question, it was properly tagged with language-lawyer, and enough code was initially presented to demonstrate the question. Just to state facts, then, the demand for an MRE was misplaced from the beginning.

It's UB. We can see this by attempting to do it in a constant expression, which causes a compile-time error:
constexpr int foo() {
    const_cast<int&>(static_cast<int const&>(42)) = 21; return 0;
}
static_assert(foo() == 0);

Clang, EDG, and GCC all give an error message saying that foo() is not a constant expression because it involves modifying a const object. (I can't test MSVC right now because Godbolt doesn't have it right now.)
The specific reason why the temporary object is const in this case is that this reference initialization is governed by [dcl.init.ref]/5.3:

A reference to type "cv1 T1" is initialized [...] as follows:

[...]
[...] If the converted initializer is a prvalue, let its type be denoted by T4; the temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied, considering the type of the prvalue to be “cv1 T4” ([conv.qual]). In any case, the reference binds to the resulting glvalue (or to an appropriate base class subobject).


Here, cv1 is const because we are initializing a const int&, so the type of the prvalue 42 is treated as const int when materializing it. This special wording creates a unique situation that is exempt from the usual rule [expr.type]/2 that prevents prvalues from having cv-qualified scalar types.
Note that this wording is fairly recent; see CWG2657.
